# How to get the text of the clicked item of Listwidget in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I was looking for a method to get a text/ name of the clicked element on a listWidget.

This was my approach looks like:

```
        # call lamp clicked event
    self.listWidget_lamps.itemClicked.connect(self.lamp_clicked)

    # call group clicked event


def lamp_clicked(self):
    self.lamp_on = True
    self.group_on = False
    lamp = Lamp(self.item.text())
    print("lamp" + self.item.text() + "got clicked")
```

but it always crashes and gives me this error:

```
lamp = Lamp(self.item.text())
AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'item'
```

Could someone please tell me what Im doing wrong?

Comment: If you get a crash, try running the program on a terminal or prompt to see the full traceback, as IDEs often hide that: you probably didn't declare `self.item`, or you used that for something else. [`itemClicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#itemClicked) has an *item* argument, which corresponds to the clicked item, add an `item` argument to `lamp_clicked` and use that.

Comment: @musicamante thanks, I got a error now (added it to the question), could you please explain to me what exactly you mean with adding the item argument to the lamp_clicked method?

Comment: Change to `def lamp_clicked(self, item):` and use `item` instead of `self.item` in that function. You get that error because there's no `self.item = ...` in your code. I suggest you to: 1. read more about classes, instance, methods and attributes; 2. As already suggested, you should ***not*** edit pyuic files, as that's considered bad practice for a lot of reasons; read [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: @musicamante thanks! someone suggested me using a other class, which is a heritage of  pyuic class, so I used that^^

Comment: If you're inheriting from *both* the pyuic class *and* QMainWindow, then it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of your slot `lamp_clicked` is wrong. Take a look at [QListWidget::itemClicked](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#itemClicked) and note that the signal has one parameter but your slot takes no parameter.

```py
def lamp_clicked(self, clickedItem):
    self.lamp_on = True
    self.group_on = False
    lamp = Lamp(clickedItem.text())
    print("lamp" + clickedItem.text() + "got clicked")
```

should do the trick.